# Can't find docker image in gitlab

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to create CI for my project and have error

> Using Docker executor with image my_host:5000/facebook-test:fb-parser ...
> Pulling docker image my_host:5000/facebook-test:fb-parser ...
> ERROR: Job failed: Error response from daemon: manifest for my_host:5000/facebook-test:fb-parser not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown (executor_docker.go:188:0s)

How can I build Image?

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
...
.build_docker_image_facebook:
  variables:
    BUILD_DIR: ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}
    IMAGE_NAME: ${CI_PROJECT_NAME}
    IMAGE_TAG: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
  dependencies: []
  needs: []
  script:
  - 'cd "${BUILD_DIR}"'
  - 'docker build --pull -t ${IMAGE_NAME}:${IMAGE_TAG} --build-arg REGISTRY_SERVER --build-arg TAG --no-cache --force-rm=true .'
  - 'docker tag ${IMAGE_NAME}:${IMAGE_TAG} ${REGISTRY_SERVER}/${IMAGE_NAME}:${IMAGE_TAG}'
  - 'docker login -u "${REGISTRY_USER}" -p "${REGISTRY_PASSWORD}" "${REGISTRY_SERVER}"'
  - 'docker push "${REGISTRY_SERVER}/${IMAGE_NAME}:${IMAGE_TAG}"'
  after_script:
  - 'docker logout "${REGISTRY_SERVER}"'


prepare_image:
  stage: .pre
  extends: .build_docker_image_facebook
  rules:
  - when: never
    if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME'
  - when: always
    changes:
    - docker/*
  - when: manual
    allow_failure: true
  variables:
    IMAGE_NAME: facebook-test
    BUILD_DIR: ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/docker

test:
  tags:
  - docker
  image: ${REGISTRY_SERVER}/facebook-test:${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
  extends: .python_unittest
...
```

Comment: Which registry are you trying to pull the image from?

Comment: It looks like the image name doesn't exist in the registry you're using. You either have mistaken the repository path or have not created the repository yet. If this is your first time pushing the image, you must create the repo for it first.